# angular-ivh-treeview - how to register callback on leaf node selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[angular-tree-view](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview) I want to dynamically load content of a file corresponding to the selected leaf node. From the documentation I am not able to figure out how can I register a callback for leaf node selection. Is there any state for leaf node selection which can be watched ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IVH Treeview allows you to [provide an expression](https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview#selectdeselect-handlers) to be run whenever a node is selected or deselected by the user:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as fancy">
  <div
    ivh-treeview="fancy.bag"
    ivh-treeview-on-cb-change="fancy.otherAwesomeCallback(ivhNode, ivhIsSelected, ivhTree)">
</div>
```

[Here's a full example](http://jsbin.com/febexe/edit?html,js,output). If you only wanted to perform an action for leaf nodes you could perhaps have `otherAwesomeCallback` check that `ivhNode` is a leaf before doing anything else.

If that doesn't work you might consider using `ivhTreeviewBfs` to create watchers on leaf nodes yourself:

```
ivhTreeviewBfs(myTree, function(node) {
  if(!node.children) {
    $scope.$watch(function() { return node.selected; }, function() {
      console.log('oh snap a leaf node changed!');
    });
  }
});
```

That's untested and not great practice, I would 100% stick the the former solution if possible. Also, be mindful that if a node becomes a leaf or stops being a leaf later on you would need to handle that too. Depending on your use case you might consider just putting change handlers on the checkboxes themselves too.

In short though, IVH Treeview does not have any particular

Comment: Is there any way to handle clicks on leafs without the checkboxes?

Comment: Sure - you'll want to use node template (https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/blob/master/docs/templates-and-skins.md). In the template just use ngClick as normal, you'll have helpers and variables in scope to determine if a leaf is being clicked on.

Comment: @jtrussell and how do I reference the method in my controller on the ngClick on the template?

Comment: @arielcr to do this you must use the v2 branch of the project and a transcluded template. Otherwise your best bet is to instead emit an event on click and handle it in your controller.